# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\karte.php:32 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I have a problem that I can't fix. In my pokemon database I want that on click on a link which shows me which Trainer I can find in the City(the city should be choose by the user as href)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <a href="?spalte=7">Malvenfroh City</a>

<?php

if (isset($_GET["spalte"])) {
 $spalte = $_GET["spalte"];
}
else {
 $spalte = 'Wurzelheim';
}

$verbindung = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pokemon', 'root', '');
$abfrage = $verbindung->query("SELECT trainer_name from trainer,ort WHERE ort_id=`".$spalte ."` AND trainer.ort_id=ort.id");
while( $row = $abfrage->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $row['trainer_name'].'<br>'; 


}
?>          

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: backticks going to kill you.

Comment: With this error message it's likely that the query fails. `$verbindung->query()` returns `false` instead of a query result set. Check `$abfrage === false`. What A-2-A means is that the error in the query could be in your use of the backtick character: `\``, it has a special meaning in MySQL, use `'` (single quote) or `"` (double quote) for strings.

Answer (score 2):

Two things :-

1.Remove ` (backticks) from your query

2.`AND trainer.ort_id=ort.id` i didn't see `ort.id` value anywhere in your code. So either remove it or try to assign value for it.

So your query will be like:-

```
$abfrage = $verbindung->query("SELECT trainer_name from trainer,ort WHERE ort_id=".$spalte);
```

Or

```
$abfrage = $verbindung->query("SELECT trainer_name from trainer,ort WHERE ort_id= $spalte");
```

**Also at the end of our discussion you need to change `PDO::FETCH_OBJ to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.**

Comment: the query must be right, i tested it myphpadmin  and it worked, this cant be the problem

Comment: i tried, still same problem.
in this line must be the problem I think:
while( $row = $abfrage->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo $row['trainer_name'].'<br>';

Comment: Now it works but i got another error

 Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\karte.php:22

Comment: Nice explanation bro